# certificate at provider for push notification in iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, provider

I need to implement iOS push notification in my app. I ve been trying this for a while and have done the iOS side code changes required. I'm able to get the device token from APNS. But im stuck with the provider side implementation.

I'm using a java provider and using JAVAPNS library to implement the provider side logic. What puzzles me is the certificate installation and stuff required at the provider.

My provider runs on unix/windows machine and I am not sure how to proceed with the SSL certificate installation here.

I have obtained SSL certificate for push notification from the apple developer site. But how do I proceed with the p12 file?

I do not find many explanations on this on the net though there are a great deal of discussions and tutorial about the iOS side implementation of push notification.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate is used to establish the socket connection to gateway.push.apple.com from your server side code.  Here is some Ruby code as an example:

```
  APN_SSL_KEY_FILE = 'lib/SSLCert_Private_Key.pem'
  APN_SSL_HOST     = 'gateway.push.apple.com'
  APN_SSL_PORT     = 2195
  APN_SSL_PASSWORD = '<password>'

  def configure_apn_cert
    @@apn_cert         = File.read(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, APN_SSL_KEY_FILE))
    @@apn_context      = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    @@apn_context.key  = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(@@apn_cert, APN_SSL_PASSWORD)
    @@apn_context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(@@apn_cert)
  end

  def create_and_configure_apn_server
    configure_apn_cert if not @@apn_cert
    puts "APN Service: Configuring APN SOCKET and SSL connection"
    @apn_socket       = TCPSocket.new(APN_SSL_HOST, APN_SSL_PORT)
    @apn_ssl          = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(@apn_socket, @@apn_context)
    @apn_ssl.sync     = true
    @apn_ssl.connect
    @apn_is_active = false;    # reopen the TCP/SSL sockets for now
  end
```

You get a .pem file with:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in myfile.p12 -out myfile.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JavaPNS, it's as simple as :

```
 import javapns.Push;

 public class PushTest {


      public static void main(String[] args) {

                Push.alert("Hello World!", "keystore.p12", "keystore_password", false, "Your token");


      }
 }
```